# Data type mismatch results in Runtime Error in C++

Tags: c++, types, runtime-error, pow

I am writing a code to calculate kth root using binary search.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
bool isPossible(long n,int k,long mid)
{
    long ans=pow(mid,k);
    if(ans<=n)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int main() {
    int t,k;
    long n;
    cin>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        cin>>n>>k;
        int s=1;
        long e=n;
        long answer=n;
        while(s<=e)
        {
            long mid=(s+e)/2;
            if(isPossible(n,k,mid))
            {
                answer=min(answer,mid);
                s=mid+1;
            }
            else
            {
                e=mid-1;
            }
        }
        cout<<answer<<endl;
    }
}
```

This code results in **Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
If I modify data type of *ans* in *isPossible()* function to double program run successfully, or if I modify the check statement to

```
    if(pow(mid,k)<=n)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

I haven't seen this kind of error because of data type mismatch, I do not understand why this happens here, cause normally storing return value of pow() in int does not cause this type of error.

Comment: Maybe you need an explicit (rather than an implicit) cast.

Comment: double -> long and long -> double won't necessary do the same comparison at the end, with rounding...

Comment: `55.000001 > 55.` but `55 <= 55`

Comment: Could it be that your process is still running in an infinite loop? If so, your IDE will have a hard time re-compiling your exe.

Comment: FYI, you should spell out your abbreviations.  Another common definition for **RE** is *regular expression*.  The time spelling out abbreviations is negligible, but it saves a lot of time when other people read your text (or you read your text at a later point).

Comment: @FiddlingBits I tried casting but it did not help.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for pointing out the difference, this difference in comparison results seems to be creating an infinite loop.